# Getting 403 error with Auth0 despite permitting all calls to that endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, auth0

I set up Auth0 with my Spring project to add authentication/authorization. It works well, but when I call the "/user/login" endpoint, I get a 403 error when it should allow all requests.

This is my custom configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

It works perfectly fine for the sign-up url.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the endpoint is the same ? check out also that the method is POST. Also, try to check if the filter on authorization is responding with the 403 code.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Turns out the body I sent with it was incorrect... Thank you though!